# Mark specific year in Time series graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a graph and I trying to mark a specific year(2020) in the graph. In my code, I mark ticker and  the year 2020 in red. I can see the ticker turned red but I don't get a line on year 2020.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong ?

```
import pandas as pd
from fairmodel import qFair
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

az = yF.plot(colormap = 'viridis', figsize= (14,7))
az.set_xlabel('Year')
az.get_xticklabels()[2].set(weight = 'heavy', color = 'red')
az.axvline(x=2020, alpha =0.5, color = 'red')
az.set_ylabel('Billion $')
az.grid(True)
az.plot()
plt.show()
```

[Figure with colored ticker and year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRdEz.png)

Comment: Maybe `az.axvline(x='2020-01-01', ...` depending on how the index of `yF` is organized.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for replying. But my year variable isn't in date format. Years are as follows: 2001, 2002, 2003...and so on. Anyway, I tried writing the way you have mentioned. It did not work. `yF` is a data frame.

Comment: Maybe your x is in string format?  If it is just the year as a number, `axvline(x=2020, ...` should work.  For strings, try `axvline(x='2020', ...`